# steam missing libgl.so.1

Tags: steam

I've tried so many things on so many forums and just can't get this to work. When I try to start steam it gives me the missing libGL.so.1 error then says "can't load steam ui". Running Ubuntu 14.04 64 with an amd 280x.

Comment: in the software center type libgl.  or try to locate  libGL.so.1 perhaps you have the file, and steam just cant find it

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the following in terminal and see if it works:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```