# Black Mesa won't start: GLIBCXX_3.4.21 missing

Tags: nvidia, games, steam

In a newly installed Ubuntu Budgie, I can't run Black Mesa through steam. I have been distant from ubuntu for 4 years and noticed that now when one runs steam from the command line it is not sending the debug error to the terminal. So if someone know how to debug steam games in ubuntu, please let me know.

What I managed to do is to find and run the executable:

```
optirun ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Black\ Mesa/bms.sh
```

However, I get the error:

```
SDL_GL_LoadLibrary(NULL) failed: Failed loading libGL.so.1: /home/luis/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Black Mesa/bin/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21`
```

- How to fix this?

I have tried the solutions in the following questions:

- [steam missing libgl.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607819/steam-missing-libgl-so-1)
- [Steam - libGL.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925978/steam-libgl-so-1?rq=1)
- [Steam - libGL.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925978/steam-libgl-so-1?rq=1)
- [Missing libGL.so.1 when trying to launch Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/731426/missing-libgl-so-1-when-trying-to-launch-steam?rq=1)
- [Steam will not run (missing libGL.so.1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707257/steam-will-not-run-missing-libgl-so-1?rq=1)
- [Program unable to find libGL.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317331/program-unable-to-find-libgl-so-1)
- [Steam - libGL.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925978/steam-libgl-so-1)
- [Error loading libGL.so.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257897/error-loading-libgl-so-1)
- [Random Source Games Stop Working After Kernel Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638104/random-source-games-stop-working-after-kernel-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling I found a solution. Since it was pretty hard to solve it, here goes the answer should someone find the same Black Mesa bug in Ubuntu.

Just rename the file libstdc++.so.6 to.old and the game will run correctly.